# NodeJS, is console.error synchronous like console.log?

Tags: node.js, logging

I just noticed something while debugging my app, console.error does not seem to execute synchronous while console.log does. I wanted to try Winston to see if it had the same behavior and indeed it did. Am I missing something here? Shouldn't logging be synchronous?

Comment: STDOUT is typically buffered, while STDERR is not.  Are you sure this isn't what's causing the problem?

Comment: This might be of interest. http://www.daveeddy.com/2012/12/06/high-performance-nodejs-logging-with-consolelog-buffering/

Comment: "The console functions are synchronous when the destination is a terminal or a file (to avoid lost messages in case of premature exit) and asynchronous when it's a pipe (to avoid blocking for long periods of time).". So I guess it depends on if you are logging to terminal, file or pipe

Comment: I'm logging to the terminal, this is strange...

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this myself. Seems like there was a Node.js bug causing this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7743